# How to record 24-bit WAV file on Linux with console?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg

It seems like `ffmpeg` supports only 16-bit record from my external microphone, but I do need the 24-bit native WAV sound. I also tried `arecord`, but it gave me this:

```
$ arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -f S24_LE output.wav
Recording WAVE 'output.wav' : Signed 24 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
arecord: set_params:1299: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S32_LE
```

Is there any way I can record 24bit WAVE file without any conversions?

Comment: Does your hardware interface support 24-bit? Do you own a mic capable of resolving sufficient detail to need 24-bit?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, it works fine with Audacity, for example, but fails when it comes to console commands.

Comment: What happens if you use the 32-bit format as indicated by the error message, and inspect the result? Possibly 24-bit with all zeroes in one byte? Any reason not to use this, or convert it if necessary?